# Customizing selected dates in mat calendar (Angular material)

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, calendar

I need to mark the days that have any task in the mat calendar, but i can´t find why is not working this code.

here goes the ts

```
 dateClass(): any {
    return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
      const findDate = this.tasks.find((task) =>
        moment(task.date_required.toDate()).isSame(moment(date), 'day')
      );
      if (findDate !== undefined) {
        console.log(findDate)
        return 'date-with-task';
      } else {
        return;
      }
    };
  }
```

these are the component imports

```
import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  OnInit,
  Output,
  SimpleChanges,
  ViewEncapsulation,
} from '@angular/core';
```

the variable tasks is an input from a parent component

```
  @Input() tasks: any[];
```

and here is the html where i use the mat calendar

```
 <div class="calendar-container" [ngStyle]="{'display': !showingCalendar ? 'none' : ''}">
        <mat-calendar class="calendar-tasks" [dateClass]="dateClass()" [(selected)]="selectedDay"
            (selectedChange)='selectedChange($event)' (monthSelected)='monthSelected($event)' [startAt]='currentMonth'>
        </mat-calendar>
        <div class="border-bottom"></div>
    </div>
```

also, i made this class in scss so i could see if the code it´s working

```
  .date-with-task{
    border-color: red;
  }
```

i read all the forums i could find and i also watched some yt videos about mat calendas, but i couldn´t find the answer. If someone could help me i'll be really grateful :)

i needed to find the days with tasks marked in red, but nothing happened

Comment: Please share the data structure of `tasks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few changes are required for your code to work as intended:

1. **Use an arrow function**

   You're currently using a regular function. Inside it, `this` is the function's scope, not the class instance.
   For access to the class instance via `this`, you have to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) <sup>***1***</sup>:

```
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() tasks: any[];

  dateClass = (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
    console.log(this.tasks) // inside your function was `undefined`
    if (someCondition) {
      return 'some-class'
    }
    return ''
  }
}
```

2. **You probably don't want to style the `<button />`**
   The class returned by the above function will be applied to `button.mat-calendar-body-cell`. If you style those buttons, two adjacent dates will touch each other. I suggest you style the inner cell content (`.mat-calendar-body-cell-content`):

```css
.test-class .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
  border-color: red;
}
```

- If you decide to style the buttons, not the cell content, note they are currently styled using `border: none`, which means you need to set more than `border-color` for the border to become visible (`border: 1px solid red;` would work); additionally, you might want to add some `border-radius` (they're boxy by default).

3. **Un-scope your (S)CSS**,
   ... because you're not styling your component's DOM elements, but inner DOM elements of `<mat-calendar>`. To remove the CSS scoping, use `ViewEncapsulation.None` (or add your styles to an un-scoped stylesheet):

```
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/54ah9m?file=src%2Fexample%2Fdatepicker-inline-calendar-example.ts) ***<sup>2, 3</sup>***.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - The function should be modified to return a string according to your business logic.
***<sup>2</sup>*** - The more verbose version of `dateClass` in the example would be:

```
dateClass = (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
  if (
    this.tasks
      .map((t) => t.date_required)
      .find((d) => moment(d).isSame(date, 'day'))
  ) {
    return 'test-class'
  }
  return ''
}
```

***<sup>3</sup>*** - Alternatively, you could type `dateClass` as `MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date>`:

```
dateClass: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date> = (date) =>
  (this.tasks
    .map((t) => t.date_required)
    .find((d) => moment(d).isSame(date, 'day')) &&
    'test-class') ||
  '';
```